# spring security requestmaps not working

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm trying to use the spring-security-core database request map config and it doesn't seem to be working for me (not working meaning not applying any restrictions).

here is my Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.xxx.Person'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.xxx.PersonRole'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.xxx.Role'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.xxx.Requestmap'
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityConfigType.Requestmap
```

Here are a few request maps in the DB:

```
requestmap/**      | ROLE_ADMIN
user/**            | ROLE_ADMIN
registrationCode/**| ROLE_ADMIN
securityInfo/**    | ROLE_ADMIN
role/**            | ROLE_ADMIN
```

However, i can login into a user without the `'ROLE_ADMIN'` role and freely access the above urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may bad... I needed to prefix the request map url with a '/' so (`'/user/**'` **not** `'user/**'`)